# To find the half value of a number using functions in C language

Tags: c, function

This is the code I wrote to find the half value of a number using functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int half(int);
void disp();

int main()
{
    disp();
}

void disp()
{
    int a, ans;
    printf("Enter a number = \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    ans = half(a);
    printf("half of a is %d\n", ans);
    printf("value of a = %d\n", a);
}

int half(int x)
{
    x = x / 2;
    printf("value of x = %d", x);
}
```

I am not getting the correct value when I add a print statement in the half function but when I remove the `printf` statement i.e `printf("value of x = %d",x)`, I get the correct result. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: How do you _return_ the result from your function? Compiler warnings are there for good reasons! Enable them and pay heed! You invoke undefined behaviour

Comment: As @Olaf has said, you aren't returning any data from the `half` function.  You've just been getting "lucky" that it sometimes puts the value of `x` on the stack when you don't return anything.

Comment: Look up the meaning of the `return` keyword in C.   Understanding it is rather fundamental to understanding how to reliably return values from functions to their callers.

Comment: **note:** you are not returning anything from your `half()` function and you are not passing a pointer as an arguments. Absent a `return` or absent passing a pointer, e.g. `half (int *);` there is no way anything you do to `x` in `half` will be reflected back in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you are not returning anything from your `half()` function and you are not passing a pointer as an argument. Absent a `return` or absent passing a pointer, e.g. `half (int *);` there is no way anything you do to `x` in `half` will be reflected back in `main()`.

Generally you want to keep the output in your calling function and reserve any output of the function to error conditions only. If you `return` the value from `half()` or pass an *integer pointer* to `half`, then you are free to use the value returned (or the updated pointer) to handle output of the halved value in `main()`. Take for example the following `half()` function:

```
int half (const int i)
{
    if (!i) return 0;
    int s = 1, v = i;
    if (i < 0) s = -1, v = -i;

    return (v >> 1) * s;
}
```

No output is generated and only the special condition where `i = 0` is handled in a special manner. The value is *returned*, so all remaining output will come from the calling function (`main()` in this case). e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int half (const int i);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int int_max = 0x7fffffff, int_min = -int_max - 1;
    long v =  argc > 1 ? strtol (argv[1], NULL, 10) : 128574;

    if (v > int_max || v < int_min) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: integer value exceeds integer storage.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n origial value : %ld\n half value    : %d\n",
            v, half ((int)v));

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** division by 2 of an *odd* numbered integer value will result in truncation, regardless of how the integer division is performed)

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fn_half

 origial value : 128574
 half value    : 64287

$ ./bin/fn_half -4

 origial value : -4
 half value    : -2

$ ./bin/fn_half -0

 origial value : 0
 half value    : 0

$ ./bin/fn_half 2147483648
error: integer value exceeds integer storage.
```

Answer (score -1):

This is undefined behavior, but if you reach the end of a function without supplying a return value in C on an x86 machine, the function may (depending on compiler, compilation options, level of optimization, etc) return the result of the last expression evaluated, stored in the `eax` register on x86. If the `printf` is there, the result is probably not `x/2`, but if the `x=x/2` is the last expression, that is what is returned.

As far as what will be returned with the `printf`: `printf` evaluates to the number of characters it outputs. So in this case, it will return 13 plus the number of digits in `x`.

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, the way to fix this is to put `return x` at the end of your `half` function.

Edit 2: To clarify, this is *undefined behavior*. The scenario I've described above is one that can happen (it's what happens for me when compiling with gcc with default optimization level). The `half` function (without `printf`) disassembles in this case to:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp #Sets up the stack frame
mov    %ecx,0x10(%rbp) #Copies parameter x by value (the `disp` function put the parameter in the ecx register)
mov    0x10(%rbp),%eax #Puts x into eax register
mov    %eax,%edx #Copy eax to edx
shr    $0x1f,%edx #This sets edx to 0 if positive, 1 if negative
add    %edx,%eax #Adds edx to eax. This insures that the next instruction gives the proper value even if eax is negative.
sar    %eax #Divides by 2 by shifting over one bit. Note that the result of x/2 is left in the eax register.
mov    %eax,0x10(%rbp) #Moves the result into x.
pop    %rbp #Restores stack frame of calling function.
retq #The calling function checks the eax register for the return value and so ends up seeing x/2.
```

If you tell the compiler to optimize, this will probably not happen. Compiling with optimization on gcc (`gcc -O3`) gives the following disassembled code for `half` (without the `printf`)

```
retq #Everything gets optimized out because the values are never used.
```

So clearly, the function is definitely not returning anything. (And doesn't get called in the first place).

This is the essence of undefined behavior. The program is allowed to do what you wanted, return some random garbage, do nothing at all, or crash horribly. Code with undefined behavior may work in some cases, only to not work at all in others.

Comment: Your claims about what happens on x86 are badly wrong.

Comment: @R.. I've tried to clarify. Am I missing something?